# How can I consume a web service sending certificate JKS using NodeJS and soap module?

Tags: node.js, soap, ssl-certificate, consumer, jks

I have to consume the web service with a JKS file, that is a certificate. I´m consuming the webservice, the code is, I´m using soap module of NPM:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'https://HOST:PORT/SERVICE?wsdl';
soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {

    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    client.Operation(args, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

The result of try this is:

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1260:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:737:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:569:12) {
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
```

I have to consume the web service with a JKS file, I don´t know how can I consume it with the file, this is necessary for a success communication.

Comment: Can you just convert .jks file to .pem one, then use it? At least that's faster, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656756/how-to-use-jks-certificate-for-node-https-client-request).

Comment: Thanks for replying me, I did that, but the problem persist because creating the client, it send petition, I need set the SSL configuration before of the create the client

Comment: Thanks for help me, your comment was helpful

Answer (score 1):

**The solution was:**

1. I'm downloaded the program keystore explorer for mac.
2. Generate the certificate from JKS file.
3. Change the method soap.createClient configuring with wsdl_options then the request was send with security parametrization.

   soap.createClient(url, { wsdl_options: { cert: fs.readFileSync('./resources/.cer', 'utf-8') } }....

Another change was, call the WSDL locally:

```
var path = require('path');
var url = path.join(__dirname, '../<path>', '<name>.wsdl');
```